# Перестали загружаться гео-объекты

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, карты, загрузка

Перестали загружаться гео-объекты без каких-либо изменений с нашей стороны.
Из 12 загружаются только 9.

Для 3х не пришедших ни .then(), ни .catch() не выполняется, хотя во вкладке Network ответ был

Версия 2.1

```
([
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/d5e/Орловская300-85.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/aef/Костромская300-85.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/36e/владимирская300-85.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/cd0/Брянская300-85.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/b2f/Ярославская30002021985.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/ff1/Тульская30002021985.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/409/Рязанская00020219-85.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/dea/Московскаяобласть30085.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/81d/ивановская300-85.kml' },
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/a6b/Москва300030219-85.kml' }, // Не приходит
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/5ed/Воронежская300-85.kml' }, // Не приходит
    { path: 'http://www.unycel.ru/upload/iblock/eea/Тверскаяобл300-85.kml' }, // Не приходит
  ]).map(function (item, index, arr) {
    var path = item.path
    // Загружаем карты из массива
    ymaps.geoXml
      .load(path)
      .then(function (res) {
        // Здесь перестал приходить ответ
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err)
      })
  });
```

Comment: Не грузятся конкретно эти три или, если поменять порядок загрузки, любые после №9 ?

Comment: Конкретно эти три. Хотя раньше они загружались без проблем.

Comment: С таким вопросом лучше обратиться напрямую в техподдержку API Яндекс.